# API for message recognition (text not speech)

Tags: java, api, kotlin, speech-recognition

I am looking for an API to detect commands in messages, similar to Google Assistant but instead of speech being just message, like a String.
I simply want to implement things like "Remind me to do x at x time", I've been searching around but every API I find is always for speech.

Comment: Answered below. Upvote and accept if it's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest experimenting with Google's Dialogue Flow. Once you wrap your brain around your use-case specific intents, entities, and contexts, you can hit the DialogueFlow API with a workflow like this:

1. The end-user types an expression.
2. Your service sends this end-user expression to Dialogflow in a
   detect intent request message.
3. Dialogflow sends a detect intent response message to your service.
   This message contains information about the matched intent, the
   action, the parameters, and the response defined for the intent.
4. Your service performs actions as needed, like database queries or
   external API calls.
5. Your service sends a response to the end-user.
6. The end-user sees the response.

Read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/basics).